# Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: xamarin.forms

After making an api call, if i input a wrong detail. My app keeps breaking with a null exception

I tried using the if-else to solve it. but it is still the same error

```
public class RemoteService
    {
        HttpClient httpClient;

        public RemoteService()
        {
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{App.BackendUrl}/");

        }


        public async Task<WeatherResponse> GetWeatherData(string query)
        {
            var weatherResponse = new WeatherResponse();
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"weather?q=" + query + App.AppID);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                weatherResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherResponse>(content);
                weatherResponse.Error = false;
                return weatherResponse;
            }
            else
            {
                //await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "City not found", "OK");
                return new WeatherResponse { Error = true };
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You are assigning something null to a var

Comment: kindly tell me how to go about it

Comment: Can you highlife the line that the error is being thrown at?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the call in a try block and catching the exception?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually from the viewmodel class. Solved